# How can I make a PHP script unload faster when it uses a LOT of memory?

Tags: php, sql, performance, memory

I have a PHP script that loads upwards of 60 million strings from a SQL call, does some processing on them, and writes them to a file. Yeah, sounds horrid, but it does the job it needs to do.

The script takes about an hour to run (mostly loading from the SQL call) which is fine.

But when it's done, it takes upwards of another hour to exit. I can only presume it's freeing up all of the memory consumed.

I tried taking out the calls to free the resources from the SQL call to see if I could just let the script end and the process end, and it makes no difference.

Am I missing something obvious? Shouldn't the script be able to exit and let the OS kill the process? The memory comes back if I kill the process by hand (sudo kill) after I know the script is done. Is there a way to make this happen and say, "look, I'm all done, just nuke yourself?"

Comment: Do you have to have all 60M strings in memory at once to do the proper processing on them?  Can this work be parallelized (i.e. via a Map Reduce prcess or similar)?

Comment: The SP that I call hands me back one, huge, result set. Since I have the memory to handle it, I simply do. That said, I could easily ask for a modification to the SP that chunks the results, but PHP isn't crafted as a particularly parallel platform. I suppose I could have a controller kick off 26 jobs, one for each result row that starts with a particular letter (for lack of a better idea on how to chunk them up), but that's some additional coding.

I was hoping that there's a "super secret" way to have a PHP process terminate immediately and let the OS recover the memory.